# Axios v0.26.0 to 1.6.0 Migration: 'message' Property Does Not Exist on Type 'never' Error

Tags: typescript, axios, typescript-typings

I am currently trying to migrate a project that uses axios 0.26.0 to uses Axios 1.6.0. I encountered an issue with the AxiosError interface. In version 0.26.0, the AxiosError interface was as follows:

```
export interface AxiosError<T = any, D = any> extends Error {
  config: AxiosRequestConfig<D>;
  code?: string;
  request?: any;
  response?: AxiosResponse<T, D>;
  isAxiosError: boolean;
  toJSON: () => object;
}
```

However, in version 1.6.0, this interface no longer exists. Instead, I only see:

```
type AxiosError<T = unknown, D = any> = InternalAxiosError<T, D>;
```

I have a piece of code in the old project like this:

```
export const throwHttpError = (error: AxiosError): Promise<IHttpErrorResponse> => {
  console.log(error?.message);
  const isCancelError = axios.isCancel(error);
  if (isCancelError) {
    return Promise.reject<IHttpErrorResponse>(
      httpError({
        statusCode: 200,
        errorMessage: error.message,
        errorKey: HttpErrorEvent.CALL_CANCELED,
      })
    );
  }

  if (error?.message === NETWORK_ERROR_MESSAGE) {
    return Promise.reject<IHttpErrorResponse>(
      httpError({
        errorMessage: 'Sorry, an error has occurred. Please refresh the page.',
        errorKey: HttpErrorEvent.NETWORK_ERROR,
      })
    );
  }
  //...
}
```

The above code tries to access error?.message, but this property does not exist in the new version. When I compile this file using tsc, I get the following exception: Property 'message' does not exist on type 'never'.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can migrate this old code to be compatible with the new AxiosError type in Axios 1.6.0? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Where are you importing `AxiosError` from? The type definition for it in 1.6.0 is not what you're seeing ~ https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v1.6.0/index.d.ts#L398

Comment: I am importing from axios like 
```import axios, {AxiosError, AxiosInstance, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';```